# How to set binding property to null if DatePickerTextBox is left empty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My `DatePickerTextBox` is binded to a property of type `DateTime?` (which allows null)

I would like to set this property to null if the `DatePickerTextBox` is left empty.

My current approach:

```
    private void TextChanged_Handler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dateTimePickerTextBox = (DatePickerTextBox)sender;
        if (dateTimePickerTextBox.Text == string.Empty)
            this.MyBindingObj.MyDate = null;
    }
```

This works, but it has the disadvantage that the `DatePickerTextBox` UI is marked as red (error), because the binding between the text and `DateTime` was not successful. Although behind the scenes everything works fine.

I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, by simply adding `dateTimePickerTextBox.Text = null;` to the previous code:

```
    private void TextChanged_Handler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dateTimePickerTextBox = (DatePickerTextBox)sender;
        if (dateTimePickerTextBox.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            this.MyBindingObj.MyDate = null;
            // Added this to avoid validation error:
            dateTimePickerTextBox.Text = null;
        }
    }
```